# How to place and scale several images in Android XML

Tags: android, xml

I have to make a splash screen for my app which consists of three logos - one is at top left of the screen, one centered both horizontally and vertically and one at bottom right (some indent from the edges would also be needed). As there are a number of ways to do it, I am a bit at loss what would be the easiest-simplest-cleanest way to do it. And so that it also scales well on different screen sizes. Any suggestions are welcome!

Logos themselves have to be scaled too - top and bottom to 1/3 of screen width and center one - 1/2 of screen width.

Comment: You can use vector images (svgs)

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you use a ConstraintLayout. If you're not familiar with that, here is a link to a codelab: [ConstraintLayout Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0). It'll allow you apply constraints to the logos so it can scale well on different screen sizes

Answer (score 1):

the two best layouts for it I believe is:

```
 RelativeLayout
 ConstraintLayout
```

you can look at the link @Mayokun suggested for the constraint layout, Ill suggest just try them both in your project and see what fits better for your needs, as for the scales of the images of 1/2 screen of 1/3 screen or any scale you want, I'll suggest you'll use :

```
 layout_weight
```

on each image(or any item else you want on you screen to be) that's the easiest way to make all the elements on the screen to scale together properly.

The `RelativeLayout` is easier for alignment (center, left, right etc) I believe.

Hope this will solve your problem, if not let us know and we'll try to help you some more, good luck mate!